# How can I parse the results of a method that I use without being familiar with .py file it was taken from?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all I would like to say that I am doing my actual first steps in Python. 
I am trying to utilize the python3-ping in my automated tests. My problem is that I don't have any experience in python and I don't know how to manipulate a .py file that I am not familiar with.
I have tried to use the following:

```
result = ping.verbose_ping('10.0.1.135', count=3)
```

But, then I printed result and it return 'None'.
I want to be able to parse the output of the ping.py script:

```
PYTHON PING 10.0.1.135 (10.0.1.135): 64 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.1.135: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.135: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.135: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0 ms

----10.0.1.135 PYTHON PING Statistics----
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip (ms)  min/avg/max = 0/0.7/0
```

One of my plans is for Instance "catch" the last line and tell the number of packets received or the packet loss percentage

```
>>> dir(result)
['__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__form
at__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__',
 '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__se
tattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Comment: It appears that function internally prints out details without returning anything. One option could be to run that code, redirect stdout to a file, and then create a new script processing that text.

Comment: Can you tell some details of the ping library you are using, then I might be able to help. Also Google regex, that's what you need

Comment: What does `dir(result)` output. Edit your answer to include that output. Also you need elevated prompt for ping to spawn icmp

Comment: I have edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I want to say that the library you picked haven't updated since 2014, looking into the source code it's not well written(looks like Java to me) and there is no a real API you could use, because all the methods are just prints the output and not returning it. So my real recommendation is - **don't use it**.

When that in mind, if you have to use it, the real issue is how do you get an output from a 3th party stdout? If you're using python3.4 and above you can use the built in `redirect_stdout`. Here is an example with your code:

```
f = StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    ping.verbose_ping('10.0.1.135', count=3)

ping_string = f.getvalue()
ping_lines = ping_string.splitlines()
```

Now it's up to you how to handle the parsing of each line inside of `ping_lines` list.

For python 2 and earlier python 3, you can look at python's source code to understand how it is implemented [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/57161aac5eb9bcb0b43e551a1937ff0a84c1ec52/Lib/contextlib.py#L275) or [this snippet](https://github.com/jackkamm/redirect_stdout2/blob/master/redirect_stdout2/__init__.py).

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to utilize the python3-ping in my automated tests.

I can't find the source code for python3-ping.

However looking at the source of https://github.com/samuel/python-ping/blob/master/ping.py we can see that the `verbose_ping` directly prints the processed output and doesn't return anything at the end (evident from result being None).

Coming on to your question, I would like to inform new python programmers that some testing frameworks suppress or redirect the `stdout` stream to `subprocess.DEVNULL` or their custom implementation. Why? To control and sanitize the output of test suite under their control, otherwise you'd get jumbled output of the test suite and your program on the same screen which can be confusing.

Sincece you are reluctant to edit Python file and I can't edit the source -- Tell me about which testing framework you are using, it may have some hidden/exotic config that dumps all prints after the test ends. (I'll edit my answer accordingly)

Comment: I have just started my exploration. Currently I am designing my own testing framework. I write "short" scripts that apply to certain Test Cases. I don't know at this point how to utilize a Testing Framework and moreover what is actually a Testing Framework

Comment: That's inspiring, reminds me of the days when I didn't know about client server mechanism and went on to write my own implementation of internet :D